# Overall brightness/gamma?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to change the overall brightness of your iOS application, as a user setting. Possibly in the appDelegate, do it can change all of the views?? Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Also, I mean for the app itself, not settings under the iOS/ users device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.5];
```

But it will only last until the application is closed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/brightness

Comment: Doing this will change the brightness of the screen within all of your views, and can be stored into NSUserDefaults, however as stated above, there is absolutely no way (without jail breaking) for your app to permanently change the devices brightness.

Answer (score 0):

To do it system wide, you can use `[UIScreen mainScreen]`'s `brightness` property, preferably in combination with a slider. (available in iOS 5.0).

If you want to do it just for your app, you may try to change the alpha value of your main window, even though I prefer the first version.